# Proving that $\sum_{i=0}^{n-p} \frac{i!}{(p+i)!} = \frac{1}{p-1}[\frac{1}{(p-1)!}-\frac{(n-p+1)!}{n!}]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, induction, factorial

I'm trying to prove that 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-p} \frac{i!}{(p+i)!} = \frac{1}{p-1}\left[\frac{1}{(p-1)!}-\frac{(n-p+1)!}{n!}\right]$$

for $p,n \geq 2$, $p, q \in \mathbb{N}$.

I'm trying to use induction but these two variables confuses me.

Can someone give me a hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Edited the left side.

Comment: edited the right side too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Induction works:
$$\frac1{p-1}\left(\frac1{(p-1)!}-\frac{(n-p+1)!}{n!}\right)-\frac1{p-1}\left(\frac1{(p-1)!}-\frac{(n-p)!}{(n-1)!}\right)\\
=\frac{(n-p)!}{p-1}\left(\frac1{(n-1)!}-\frac{n-p+1}{n!}\right)=\frac{(n-p)!}{p-1}\frac{p-1}{n!}=\frac{(n-p)!}{n!}$$
So the difference of two successive right hand sides gives us the last term in the sum on the left. The base case is trivial when you start at $n=p-1$.

Comment: Maybe the downvoter could explain how is the question sensible?

Comment: Wolframalpha says it's valid for p, n > -2.

Comment: But you're right. Maybe there's another constraint.

Comment: edited the left and right side.